# How to get git to ignore directory on my server?

Tags: git, github, gitignore

Let's say my repo looks like this:

`myApp
  public
    index.html
    ...
  tests
    foo.js
    ...`

I want the `tests` folder to get pushed to GitHub but NOT to my server. How do I accomplish this?

Since I want `tests/` to get pushed to GitHub I cannot simply add `/tests/*` to my .gitignore file.

I've tried adding `/tests/` to the `.git/info/exclude` file on my server, then deleting the contents of `/tests` but this did not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "my server"?  Is it another remote?  Are you using Git as a release tool?

Comment: Yes. To update my app, I ssh into my server then 'git pull origin master'. I want git on my server to ignore the tests folder when I pull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Schwern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14660/schwern) said if you actually still want to use git for releases the best choice is make another branch for releases. The steps can be:

In your machine:

```
A-->B-->C-->D          -development
    \       \
     `->v1---`->v2     -releases
```

Create the **releases branch**

```
git branch releases
git checkout releases
```

You can then remove the **test** folder in **releases branch**

```
git rm myApp/test
git commit
```

and merge it with **development branch** without the folder:

```
git merge --no-commit development
```

then you can push the whole project to GitHub. Then in the server you can do:

```
git pull origin releases
```

In order to only get the **releases branch** so you will have this structure in your server.

```
->v1----->v2      -releases
```

Answer (score 0):

`.gitignore` and `.git/info/exclude` don't ignore changes.  They only say what to consider untracked.  Once a file is tracked, they have no effect.

It sounds like you're using Git as a release tool and have run into one of the many problems with that.  Version control is a poor release tool.  I would suggest instead using a release/packaging system instead.

There can be benefits to using a git checkout in production.  For one, if anything is hot patched it will be obvious.  But you'll need a release process.

- Make a release branch off your development branch.
- Delete the tests directory in the release branch.
- Checkout the release branch on your production server.

When you're ready to release...

- `git checkout release`
- `git merge --no-commit devel`
- Discard the tests directory if it has been readded by the merge.
- Commit the merge.
- ssh to production and pull.